# Not able to install Powershell module in Corporate environment

Tags: powershell, proxy, powershell-4.0, powerbi-rest-api

I am new to Powershell and I have to write one script to automate some process, so I used below command

Install-Module -Name MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt
PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt'. Try Get-PSRepository to see
all available registered module repositories.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1809 char:21

- ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
- ```
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exception
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage

I have tried manual installation of this library but that too got failed. I feel it has something to do with network settings but I dont know exactly.

Comment: Did you try running Get-PSRepository